# Refreshing property in ViewModel of Window with EventAggregator from another class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

So.. I have some core-class. While it is loading some modules I am trying to send some notifications to status-window with EventAggregator.GetEvent().Publish(). 
Status window showing:

```
private Core()
        {
            SystemManager.EventAggregator.GetEvent<StartProgressWindow>().Publish(null);
            this.InitializeCore();
        }
```

Where StartProgressWindow is starting status-window event and InitializeCore method is where all the modules are loading.

Status notifications sending:

```
Core.EventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeProgressStatus>().Publish("Some module is loading");
```

And subscriber:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeProgressStatus>().Subscribe((message) =>
                {
                    this.Status = message;
                });
```

Status property:

```
public string Status 
        {
            get
            {
                return status;
            }
            set
            {
                this.status = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Status");
            }
        }
```

Binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Status, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And, actually, the problem:

Property changes with all the statuses that I'm sending it to. But it does not reflects on UI, it is forzen. I set the value of the Status-property to "Some string" in constructor of ViewModel's class and of course it reflects well. 
What I am doing wrong?
Thanks,
Pavel!

Comment: I don't think the above piece of code is blocking the UI thread, probably some other thread causing the issue. Put your breakpoint on Subscriber and see what is happening.

Comment: I was thinking the same way! And already did this. And All good in the Subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making sure you're subscribing on the UI thread?

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<ChangeProgressStatus>().Subscribe((message) =>
                {
                    this.Status = message;
                }, ThreadOption.UIThread);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is because all your events are being handled at the same time as the `InitializeCore()` method is, so it doesn't actually render anything until all the events and the `InitializeCore()` method have finished

Try launching your `StartProgressWindow` event on a lower [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) then `Render`, such as `DispatcherPriority.Background`

```
private Core()
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
        new Action(delegate 
        { 
            SystemManager.EventAggregator.GetEvent<StartProgressWindow>().Publish(null);
        }));

    this.InitializeCore();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and, as I expect, publishing the event ChangeProgressStatus Subscriber do not fired!

Comment: @shtpavel Try using the `Dispatcher` for publishing the `ChangeProgressStatus` message instead of the `StartProgressWindow` message. Also just to verify, you only have one copy of the `EventAggregator` in your code, correct? You're not working with two separate instances of the `EventAggregator`?

Comment: EventAggregator is a singleton ^)

Comment: Thanks for help! i'll try it soon and I will write does it work or not!